# How can I hide letter counter at the bottom of TextBox in MaterialDesign

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

[image: TextBox with character counter at the bottom.]

In latest version of MaterialDesign WPF this problem is showing.
Is there any property or something else to hide it?

- MaterialDesignThemes Version 4.0.0
- MaterialDesignColors Version 2.0.0

Code:

```
<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="First Name" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" MaxLength="50"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is already an issue on GitHub concerning how to hide the character counter.

- [How disable CharacterCounter on TextBox](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/2247)

It is already confirmed that there will be a way to disable it in the upcoming release.

> In the next release there will be a new attached property you can use to hide the character counter.
>
> ```
> <TextBox
>    MaxLength=""10""
>    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.CharacterCounterVisibility=""Collapsed""/>
> ```

In the meanwhile you can either downgrade to a previous version of MaterialDesign, as this feature was [introduced in version 4.0](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/releases/tag/v4.0.0) or you can use the [workaround suggested in the issue](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/2247#issuecomment-780192000).

```
<TextBox>
    <materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.CharacterCounterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" />
    </materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.CharacterCounterStyle>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I cannot downgrade the version because other dependencies also there. currently I'll remove the MaxLength="50"  property and will check max length programmatically in C# while validation.

Comment: @SandeepJadhav You do not necessarily have to downgrade, the workaround should work.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, i am using version 4.0, i used this to remove the counter:

```
materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.CharacterCounterStyle="{x:Null}"
```